# Eclipse PlugIn Project get existing Projects of the workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am totally confused with the plugin procedures.

To be more precise: I am struggling to access the classes/projects of my workspace. I wrote an Eclipse PlugIn Project that is supposed to access my workspace and to parse one of the projects. I actually took the code from here [Link]http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html#using-the-ast!

My problem is that do not receive my projects on my workspace. With this code only the RemoteSystemsTempFiles are returned:

```
     public class SampleHandler  {

public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    // Get the root of the workspace
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
    // Get all projects in the workspace
    IProject[] projects = root.getProjects();
    // Loop over all projects
    for (IProject project : projects) {
        System.out.println(project.getName());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do I access the right workspace? I want to access the workspace of my plugIn project (c:/workspace) and not the workspace of the eclipse instance that is opening when I run the project.

I also tried

```
     IPath path = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation();
```

This returns C:/runtime-EclipseApplication

And

```
    File file = new File("C://workspace");
    URI location = file.toURI();
    IFile[] files=ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findFilesForLocationURI(location);
```

The files Array's length is 0.

How can I get all of my projects?

Comment: When you run your plugin as a Eclipse Application a new workspace is created for your testing. You can't access anything in your developement workspace from there. You can create new projects in the test workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I use my plugin project in my actual workspace. I created a plugin project with a view and dont want to have that view in my test workspace, but in my development workspace

Comment: You have to export the plugin and then install it in to your main Eclipse to do that. This should only be done when the plugin is finished, for development testing you really have to do everything in the test workspace.